Should I include unannotated transcripts in a pathway enrichment analysis of a de-novo assembled transcriptome?
I'm trying to perform an enrichment analysis on a set of Transcripts assembled de-novo, using a GSEA like method on KEGG and GO. The set contains annotated and unannotated transcripts. My question is:

Should I include the Transcripts which don't have a GO and/or KEGG term?
Will it matter whether it is included or excluded?

Thanks for your kind help.
